# php form and database structure

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm building a php registration form for a college events.

I have already coded a php register and log in system.

- To register user must entry his name, email id, college id and password.
- After this , his account is created now he can fill form to participate in events.

There are 2 types of categories

- under 1st category there are 10 events,
- and same for 2nd category.
- Each user can register for 3 events in each category.
- some events require a team, so in form they have to entry thr team member details.
- and if a user is already participated, In an event under 1st category with his team, I want that the same user can only participate for 2 more events under 1st 
  category.

Solutions I'm thinking

- I can give only 3 options to register. this will limit total number of participation for each user to 3 after filling 3rd form he can't register.
- Making a column against each id named 'reg_count' for every new user its value is set to '0' and as he fill his 1st form this changes to '1' and so on till '3' .
- when 'reg_count' value is '3' user can't register anymore.

My problem -

- If a user want to participate in an event which require a team say 5 team members.
- How can I update value of 'reg_count' for 5 team members?
- and say 4th team member is not registered on site yet.

  But still he participating for one event with his team.
- now he decide to make his account, to participate in other event.

  I want that he should only get 2 options now in his account. As he is register already in one event.

how should I code this ... ?

Comment: I would not go with updating the `reg_count` field, but rather create separate tables for `users`, `user_events` etc. Besides, this does not seem like a stackoverflow question. This is DB architecture question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make another table witch has data about relationship between team members. it would looks like this.

```
index, teamId(int), userId(int)
0,     1,               1
1,     1,               5
2,     2,               3
```

so user 1,5 are same team, and 3 is alone. and index is auto increase, userid would be index of user table. and teamId could be int or string whatever you want.

and you can get the all team member's college id, when they publish the team. if they want to 4 member team? than he/she has to input all their college id. and check team table's id when new user sign in.